Difference in Data Fetching Behavior in Astro Project
I have the following code in my Astro project:
//api.js
export const fetchKnowledgeBases = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/accounts/${accountId}/knowledge-bases/${kbId}`)
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch knowledge bases')
    }
    await sleep(7000)
    const data = await response.json()
    return data
}

const knowledgeBase = await fetchKnowledgeBases()

export {knowledgeBase}

// index.astro
---
import {fetchKnowledgeBases} from '../../../services/api'

const a = await fetchKnowledgeBases()
console.log(a)
---

<Homepage />

When I refresh the page with the code above, it takes 7 seconds to fetch the data. However, when I use the following code:
// index.astro
---
import {knowledgeBase} from '../../../services/api'

console.log(knowledgeBase)
---

<Homepage />

The data seems to load instantly on page refresh. It appears to fetch the data only once when I run "npm run dev", and subsequent refreshes use the cached data.
Question:
Why does the second approach load the data instantly on page refresh, while the first approach takes 7 seconds? Can someone explain the difference in behavior?
Feel free to ask if you need any further adjustments!

I'm not sure what you're confused about. As you discovered, the 7 seconds are always spent: either on page request, or only once when you start the server (or if you're doing static-site-generation when you generate the page). Or are you asking why it takes 7 seconds? Apparently it's a slow api.
